# Input a list of lists Python (eg. input() [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])

Tags: python

```
[[9,8,9],[9,8,9]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\224.py", line 15, in <module>
    c =  list(map(int, input().split()))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[[9,8,9],[9,8,9]]'
```

Here is the code below.

```
c =  list(map(int, input().split()))
```

I didn't find any luck so far with Google searching and what I found on Stackexchange was confusing mainly because I'm a noob.

So what is my obvious mistake that I can't figure out?

What's the best way to input a list of lists as I intend?

Comment: What are you `input()`-ing?

Comment: @rdas This. [[9,8,9],[9,8,9]]

Comment: Do you know what `split()` splits on?

Comment: And what are you expecting out of it? It's a string so when you split it nothing happens because by default splitting happens by whitespace. So that whole string is being passed to `int()` - which is what the error is telling you.

Comment: You can also do, ``import ast; ast.literal_eval("[[9,8,9],[9,8,9]]")``

Answer (score 2):

Your structure is a valid json value, so you can parse it as such:

```
import json
json.loads('[[9,8,9],[9,8,9]]')
=> [[9, 8, 9], [9, 8, 9]]
```